# How to use bash dialog --yesno correctly

Tags: bash, shell, dialog, stdout

I want a simple Yes/No dialog and do make an action dependent on the users choice. My try so far:

```
operation=$(dialog --stdout --title "What to do?" \
                --backtitle "Backup-Verwaltung" \
                --yesno "Yes: Delete, No:  Restore" 7 60)

    if [[ $operation == true ]]; then
        dialog --title "Information" --msgbox "TRUE" 6 44
    else
        dialog --title "Information" --msgbox "FALSE" 6 44
    fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `--yesno` flag returns with the exit status (0 = Yes, 1 = No). Simply check it:

```
if dialog --stdout --title "What to do?" \
          --backtitle "Backup-Verwaltung" \
          --yesno "Yes: Delete, No:  Restore" 7 60; then
    dialog --title "Information" --msgbox "TRUE" 6 44
else
    dialog --title "Information" --msgbox "FALSE" 6 44
fi
```

Alternative the exit status is stored in `$?`, which can be saved for later:

```
dialog --stdout --title "What to do?" \
  --backtitle "Backup-Verwaltung" \
  --yesno "Yes: Delete, No:  Restore" 7 60
dialog_status=$?

# Do something

if [ "$dialo_status" -eq 0 ]; then
  # The previous dialog was answered Yes
else
  # The previous dialog was answered No or interrupted with <C-c>
fi
```

Comment: If "No" should be selected by default, the argument or the parameter --defaultno helps.